# Possible bug with jQuery dragenter/dragleave?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag-and-drop

```
var df =  $("#dropfiles");
df.on('dragenter', function (e)      
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass("outside").addClass("inside");
    console.log("dragenter");
});
df.on('dragleave', function (e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass("inside").addClass("outside");
    console.log("dragleave");
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/82zbdxon/19/

Under firefox 42.0, `dragleave` + `dragenter` pairs are called on my computer when I drag a file over the `#dropfiles` element and start moving it slowly over it. Here is a screenshot that shows an example: a file is being dragged over the `#dropfiles div`, and the class of the `div` is `outside` instead of `inside`.

[image]

Under Chrome browser, it seems to be working fine.

Can this be an error in jQuery? Or maybe in Firefox?

UPDATE: Tested on Firefox 42, IE 11, Opera 33 and Chrome 46. Only Firefox has this problem. So I guess this is a firefox bug? Still not sure.

Comment: just try .. use  .on('dragenter dragover'  .. I used dragover before in firefox and it worked fine .. but I really didn't test dragenter before .. and I don't have firefox installed right now to test it

Comment: I think you did not understand the question. I'm already using dragenter. But it is called when it should not be called.

Comment: I have filed a bug report here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1226492 if this is a real bug then we may want to remove this question from stack overflow.

Comment: This was confirmed by mozilla. It is a bug indeed. I'm not sure if this question should be closed or not.

Comment: Don't close or remove it .. it may be helpful for someone else